# rewrite-rule to properly handle ?-sign

Tags: php, regex, apache, url-rewriting, cherokee

I'm having a annoying issue with rewrite-using cherokee web-server.

I want to convert:

```
http://example.com/mypage.phtml?cmd=print
=> to =>
http://example.com/index.php?page=mypage&cmd=print
```

The problem is that the ?-sign messes up the cmd;

```
$_GET : array('page'=>'mypage', '?cmd'=>'print')
```

Cherokee is configured with:

```
regexp: ^/(.*)\.phtml(.*)$
internal subst: /index.php?page=$1&$2
```

So my question: How to best "eat up" the question-mark *if present*.

Regards,

//teson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try matching it explicitly before the capturing parentheses:

```
regexp: ^/(.*)\.phtml\??(.*)$
```

`\?` is a literal `?`, and the following `?` means "match 0 or 1 times".